# How to set initial value to ng-model select option?

Tags: angularjs

```
<select ng-model="sortOrder">
    <option value="country">Country (A-Z)</option>
    <option value="-country">Country (Z-A)</option>
</select>
```

controller:

```
 $scope.sortOrder = ['-country', 'name'];
```

I have it set up something like this. It works otherwise but the select option by default is just empty. I would like the first option to be selected by default or even just some text there.. basically anything but an empty dropdown. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: On your controller: `$scope.sortOrder = 'country'`

Comment: Yea an array is not a valid model option

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)**

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options=" item.name for item in items"></select>
```

now to set the default option while creating list of items or If you are getting item list dynamically than you can assign the first item as a default item such

```
$scope.items = [{'name': 'Select Item'},
                       {'name' : 'Google Calendar'},
                       {'name' : 'Jira'},
                       {'name' : 'Zendesk'}];

//This will set the default item as selected.
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
```

Let me know if its still not clear.

Comment: I need to assign a text (different each row) and a different value for each text. This way I can only assign different values to 'name', right? @CrazyGeek

Comment: Yes you can add more attributes in each item so you can have access item.value and one more thing if you wanna assign some custom attributes like css classes for each option than you should create a custom directive.

Comment: And how do I add more attributes? I would need at least three or more for every item. Now it's just basically one value for each different name row. And when I do the for-loop how do I access the other attributes? Like if this is a dropdown menu there's typically at least a text and a value for every item. @CrazyGeek

Answer (score 0):

You can use "selected" attribute for `<option>` on init:

```html
<select ng-model="selecteditem">
<option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item}}" {{item===selecteditem ? 'selected' : ''}}></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does not work, the browser sanatizes the `{{item===selecteditem ? 'selected' : ''}}` section